# Reshape/Reposition dataframe using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, reshape

I have a dataframe `df` as following:

[image: df]

I want to reshape/reposition from `df` into `df2` as following:

[image: df2]

I have tried, but it gave a strange result (please see my code)

Appreciate any suggestions here.

```
# initialize data of lists.

data = {'Source': ['Rainfall', 'SP2', 'SP2', 'Inflow','Rainfall','Inflow', 'Inflow', 'Inflow','SWT','SP1','SP1','SWD'],
        'Target': ['SP1', 'Evp', 'Outflow', 'SP2','SWD','SWD', 'SP2','SP1','SP1','SP2','Evp','Loss']}  

#Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

#Defined variables

vals = ['SP1', 'SWD', 'SP2']

tmp = (df.mask(df['Target'].isin(vals))
         .fillna(df.rename(columns={'Target': 'Source', 'Source': 'Target'}))
      )
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(tmp))
```

Comment: What is the problem? Your code seems to work.

Comment: it does not generate the desired outputs (please see the attached df2)

Comment: Use: `pd.DataFrame(columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(tmp.sort_values(by='Source')))`

Comment: Hi Mozway, Thanks. it is around to what i am up to. But if you look at my expected df2, it is missing some values. 
for example, in column SP1, i want to see Target as: Rainfall, Inflow, SWT, SP2, Evp

Comment: @PonlokPeter that's because you don't have this pair in your `tmp` frame

Comment: If you want specific combinations in a specific order, why don't you manually create the Multi index?

Comment: Hi Vilaizzare and mozway, would you be able to give me some direction?